# Using the append model to do partial row updates in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Suppose I have the following record in BQ:

```
id        name           age    timestamp
1         "tom"          20     2019-01-01
```

I then perform two "updates" on this record by using the streaming API to 'append' additional data -- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery. This is mainly to get around the update quota that BQ enforces (and it is a high-write application we have).

I then append two edits to the table, one update that just modifies the `name`, and then one update that just modifies the `age`. Here are the three records after the updates:

```
id        name           age    timestamp
1         "tom"          20     2019-01-01
1         "Tom"          null   2019-02-01
1         null           21     2019-03-03
```

I then want to query this record to get the most "up-to-date" information. Here is how I have started:

```
SELECT id, **name**, **age**,max(timestamp)
FROM table
GROUP BY id 
-- 1,"Tom",21,2019-03-03
```

How would I get the correct name and age here? Note that there could be thousands of updates to a record, so I don't want to have to write 1000 case statements, if at all possible.

For various other reasons, I usually won't have all row data at one time, I will only have the RowID + FieldName + FieldValue.

I suppose plan B here is to do a query to get the current data and then add my changes to insert the new row, but I'm hoping there's a way to do this in one go without having to do two queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, 
  ARRAY_AGG(name IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] name,
  ARRAY_AGG(age IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] age,
  MAX(ts) ts  
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY id
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, "tom" name, 20 age, DATE '2019-01-01' ts UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, "Tom", NULL, '2019-02-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, NULL, 21, '2019-03-03' 
)
SELECT id, 
  ARRAY_AGG(name IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] name,
  ARRAY_AGG(age IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] age,
  MAX(ts) ts  
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY id
```

with result

```
Row id  name    age ts   
1   1   Tom 21  2019-03-03
```

Comment: I've run into one thought here that I didn't have when I initially posted the question: what if the value that is being updated is set to null? For example, if the age goes from being 20 to being null? How would you suggest dealing with a case like that?

Comment: you can use `RESPECT NULLS` instead of `IGNORE NULLS` - in this case name will be retirned as `NULL` for example

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case of application of analytic functions in Standard SQL.

Here is how you can achieve your results:

```
select id, name, age from (
  select id, name, age, ts, rank() over (partition by id order by ts desc) rnk
  from `yourdataset.yourtable`
)
where rnk = 1
```

This will sub-group your records based `id` and pick the one with most recent `ts` (indicating the record most recently added for a given `id`).

Comment: how would the performance of this compare with the above answer? Also, I'm fairly certain this could run into an out-of-memory error from bq if partitioning by id, couldn't it?